# PHP time is not properly match from my server

Tags: php, datetime, time

My computer clock show me 11:58 PM but my PHP clock show me 07:58 PM,
Why that happen I don't know but I try many kind of codes but that doesn't work. this is my screen shot of my problem;

[image]

Comment: Look into this: [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: @AsifUzZaman: What kind of variable

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It is very simple I was tested in my localhost, here is the solution.

```
<?php

$hoursver = "4"; // hours set and adjust you time properly

// time is behind the server time
$timeadjust = ($hoursver * 3600);

$real_time = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",time() + $timeadjust);


echo $real_time;
?>
```

here is the result:

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Jasmin This may _appear_ to work, but it is __not__ the correct solution to your problem. See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php).

Comment: @vascowhite: but sir that script works properly, because my localhost time setting and my online server time setting is different from each other.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the time zone is different.Use this function to set the time zone.

```
date_default_timezone_set ("your-Time-Zone" );
```

For more details check, [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
```

Try This Code

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem with the timezone for the PHP use the following function and put it in the top of your page.

```
date_default_timezone_set()
```